# Get the value of the first option in a select list using jQuery

Tags: jquery

This always returns null for some reason?

```
 alert($(element).val("option :first-child").val());
```

Comment: how have you defined `element`?

Comment: element is a select which is passed from somewhere

Comment: Lets have closer look at your call: `$(element)` makes `element` a jQuery object. `.val("option :first-child")` sets the value of that object (literally) to the character sequence `"option :first-child"`. `.val()` gets the value of `$(element)`. I hope it's clear that this cannot work.

Comment: I know but if you've defined it as `var element=$('select')` there's no need to put it inside parentheses again, also remove the space after option, there's no need for that, and most importantly instead of `$(element).val(...` use `$(element).children(...`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will vary slightly depending on what the `element` variable actually is, but:

If `element` is a native DOM element:

```
alert($(element).find("option:first-child").val());
```

Or if `element` is a jQuery-wrapped element already you can simplify to:

```
alert(element.find("option:first-child").val());
```

---

There were two bugs in what you were trying:

- You were using `val` in place of `find` to find the `option` within the `select`
- You had a space between `option` and `:first-child`, which means "find a first-child **which is a descendant of** an option element"

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're setting the val (to "option :first-child") then trying to read it. Maybe you meant to do this?

```
alert($(element).find("option:first-child").val());
```